# Modal return data type checking

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Can I give the `type` for the returned data here `modal.onDidDismiss(data =>`? It seems not working. I would like to have `compile-time` `type` checking for the returned data too. Any clue?

It gives this error:

> [ts] Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.(parameter) Transaction: any

When I tried this:

```
 modal.onDidDismiss(data:Transaction => {
      this.transactions.push(data);
    });
```

*My original method:*

```
goToTransaction() {
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create('TransactionPage');
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        this.transactions.push(data);
    });
    modal.present();
  }
```

Comment: you mean `modal.onDidDismiss(data:Type =>{})` gives error?

Comment: Yes. `[ts] Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.
(parameter) Transaction: any
` @suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to use parenthesis or grouping operator on your parameter and type to ensure TS compiler knows that you are referring to one parameter and its type.

```
 modal.onDidDismiss((data:Transaction) => {
      this.transactions.push(data);
});
```

Comment: Yes, That was the issue. Thanks a lot :)